# Xcode 10 App installation failed, unknown error has occurred

Tags: ios, xcode, xcode10

When I am installing for the first time it is running. But from the second run to the same device Xcode is throwing this alert.

I found lot of answers for other Xcode version and tried the following,

- Clean project
- Clear Derive data
- Quit Xcode
- Restarted my system
- Restarted my device
- unplugged the cable and reattached
- Have valid provisioning profile.

Any help would mean alot to me! I am using Xcode 10.2 with Swift 3.0, running on a iOS 11.2.1 device.

[image]

Comment: As I understand, you have already tried to cleanup application's build folders, DerivedData...  And caches and also tried to manually delete Xcode, and it's caches from Library folder and reinstall it from zerro?

Comment: I haven't tried reinstalling Xcode.

Comment: @Igor even reinstalling Xcode didn't help. :(

Comment: have you clean the caches? ~/Library/Caches/com.apple.dt.Xcode

Comment: no, Instead I re-checkout the codebase at different location.

Comment: @Igor again this issue occurs. :(

Comment: Sorry, I have no more stupid ideas )
Full cleanup have did the thing for me, however it was much earlier, Xcode 9, as I remember...

Answer (score 0):

For me this solution worked

Xcode -> Preferences -> Locations -> Derived Data -> Delete it... It will clean your project, Try to restart your device. Then build the app on the device.

Comment: Did you check UDID of your iPhone added in provisioning profile.